# Change default tax class in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have been looking in the admin of Magento to change the default tax class that is set in Magento, but can not find how to change this. We have always 21% tax and have set up all the tax rules. When a new product is made we want it to have this tax class by default instead of the default one without tax.

Hope this is not to hard?

Comment: as far as I know there is no way to determine a default tax class for new products. It could obviously done within a specific dev, but I don't think that's what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

If you mean in the product tab 
So you can rewrite the method getAllOptions() to put the tax class you want as default in the select

```
// File path : app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Class/Source/Product.php

class Mage_Tax_Model_Class_Source_Product extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
```

If you mean pragmatically after product import or something

You can implement observer on  product save to set the class ID you want.

```
           <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <set_tax_class>
                        <class>module/observer</class>
                        <method>METHODNAME</method>
                    </set_tax_class>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
```